# Getting Fastest MySql Query

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

I am developing a CodeIgniter application with Mysql database which will contain lots of data.

My Query is like below

`SELECT id, code, name, category, purchase_price, retail_price, expiry_date, color_code, sub_category FROM products ORDER BY id DESC`

In this regard How can I make Fastest `SELECT` Query ?

How can I measure Query execution time ?

Comment: If `id` be the primary key from your table, then this query should already be reasonably fast.

Comment: Limit to 10 results.

Comment: Thanks @TomShaw, But I am using DataTable jQuery plugin to display data. Thanks.

Comment: @TomShaw, I know Limiting to 10 row is faster. Thanks.

Comment: Create an index on ```id``` if it does not exist yet. This will at least optimize the sorting away. For loading all the data from disk.. well, there is nothing in the query you could do. Optimize your hardware.

Comment: No filtering with `WHERE`?  `id` is the `PRIMARY KEY`?  It is optimal as it stands.  But, if you are _paginating_, then there is a lot that can be done.  But say so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to make the query the absolute fastest is to limit the columns your selecting to what's absolutely necessary, id, price, color etc. Large data sets should always be server side paginated. Client side pagination is almost completely useless in the real world. Before you execute your query run:

```
SET profiling = 1;
```

After the query is finished.

```
SHOW PROFILES;
```

Answer (score 1):

For this query:

```
SELECT id, code, name, category, purchase_price, retail_price, expiry_date, color_code, sub_category
FROM products
ORDER BY id DESC;
```

There is little you can do from an optimization perspective *other than* optimizing the `ORDER BY`.  The best index would be:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_products_id_desc ON products(id desc);
```